# Accessing a user details from a page application

Tags: php, facebook

I have seen examples of accessing users data in canvas application with oAuth and graph api. But what I want to do is access user data such as the name, email address and photo within a page tab application. I have looked around and seen no examples. I am wondering if this is possible and how I would access the user data and yes I would like to do it through oAuth(asking them for the data).

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same exact way you do it for Canvas Apps:

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;

     $canvas_page = YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL;

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

If you need to access the user email just add the `scope` parameter (with the `email` permission) to your authentication url.